# canvas and js basic game with colors

Tags: javascript, canvas, colors

does anybody know why black lines from the begining disappear after some time? it is really hard to post on this site it took me 30mins fr

```
elemTop = c.offsetTop + c.clientTop;
c.addEventListener("click", function(event){
var x = event.pageX - elemLeft,
y = event.pageY - elemTop;
let i = Math.floor(x/50)
let j = Math.floor(y/50)
colorit(i,j)})`

`function drawthis(i,j){
ctx.moveTo(i * 50,  j * 50 );
ctx.lineTo(i * 50 + 50,  j * 50);
ctx.lineTo(i * 50 + 50,  j * 50 + 50 );
ctx.lineTo(i * 50,  j * 50 + 50);
ctx.moveTo(i * 50,  j * 50 );
ctx.stroke();}`

`function givrand (){
return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);}

function colorit(i,j){
let r = givrand();
let g = givrand();
let b = givrand();
> `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(" + r + "," + g +"," + b + ", 0.3)";
ctx.fillRect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);}
`
setInterval(function(){
let i = Math.floor(Math.random()*(600/50));
let j = Math.floor(Math.random()*(600/50));
colorit(i,j)
},10);


for (let i =0 ; i < 600/50; i++){
for(let j = 0; j < 600/50; j++){
drawthis(i,j)
}}``
`
please help! thanx if you can tell me how to fix this i would be grateful !!!! 
it is for my first project still new to all this js and html css 
new to stack owerflow tooo
```

Comment: You're missing the html and css that you use to create your canvas. c, ctx, elemLeft, and elemTop are not defined in the javascript you've provided. You've incorrectly tagged the BASIC programming language. To answer your question though - it looks like you draw your grid, and then repeatedly draw colored rectangles above the grid. After a while, all of these .03 alpha rectangles stack up to form an opaque color so you don't see any lines.

Comment: thank you! Ihave html and css just didnt post them here